# Storing Spanish characters in MSSQL Database

Tags: python, sql-server, database, utf-8, python-2.x

I need to store the Spanish characters `á,é,í,ó,ú,ü,ñ,¿,¡` in the MSSQL 2014 Database having `iso-1` as the `character set` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` as the `collation name`.

I am getting this as `utf-8` encoded data in my application server running a Python 2.x based web-framework.

Since we still don't support `nvarchar` in the database, and it seems like the character set supports Spanish, is it correct to do something like: `a.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')` and store it in the database? While retrieving we will again convert it back to `utf-8`.

```
>>> spanish_utf8 = "á,é,í,ó,ú,ü,ñ,¿,¡"

>>> spanish_latin_1 = spanish.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')
'\xe1,\xe9,\xed,\xf3,\xfa,\xfc,\xf1,\xbf,\xa1'
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what database and API you're talking about exactly.

Comment: Yes, that should work. It will even work for those chars if the encoding is actually cp1252 rather than proper Latin1. Why don't you test it? Another option is to encode the data to Unicode escape sequences so it can be saved as pure ASCII.

Comment: @deceze, I have added all the details. Hope the 'downvote' can be removed :-).

Comment: Yeah @PM2Ring. Thanks. That is another approach especially if we have to support all the Unicode characters. But here it seemed like the cleanest solution as we only needed Spanish support.

Comment: Sure, `.encode('latin-1')` is simple, and it uses less disk space. BTW, your 1st line is a little misleading: `spanish_utf8 = "á,é,í,ó,ú,ü,ñ,¿,¡"` is a Unicode string, it's not UTF-8... unless you're using Python 2, and the script has a UTF-8 coding directive. And in which case, the string should really be a Unicode string: `u"á,é,í,ó,ú,ü,ñ,¿,¡"`. Although Python 2 allows you to put non-ASCII chars into plain strings it's a recipe for trouble, IME.

Comment: Yeah, @PM2Ring thanks for pointing that out, I have added  Python 2.x to the question. I don't think the latter can be used in production, it can trouble your sleep in future ;-)

Comment: Unicode handling in Python 3 is a lot saner... In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.